# What is a way to print a design onto coffe cup lids?

Tags: print-design, software-recommendation

Considering the plastic that coffee cup lids are made from what would be the best quality way to print onto that, that wouldn't transfer of rub off?

Comment: A direct to substratoe printer MIGHT work. Something like the demo piece ofn this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ynmU6NSqCUQ#t=85) so you might ask for this and test. No idea if it would stick

Answer (score 3):

I've been in the print / sign industry for over 14 years and do not know any way, quality or otherwise that would allow you to print on a coffee cup lid.

The formed plastic shape of the lid would in my mind at least inhibit many of the printing processes that exist, and I don't know how feasible it is to have the lid manufacturer print before forming the lids, as the heat and stress would probably destroy the print.

If you are DIY then I suppose you could make a custom pad press but it seems to be a lot of trouble when you could print on the cup itself or a "Starbucks" type sleeve much easier. Just search "print coffee cup sleeves" on Google for a long list of vendors.

Alternatively if you have a huge run (20,000pcs or more) you could have the lids custom formed to have raised lettering or logos that won't fade or rub off.

Comment: If one has a lot of cash then it would be possible to inject 2 different plastics. Some Direct-to-Substrate inkjets could also do this.